# How to nest events after .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think the solution might be obvious, but I cant seem to find it...

```
this.$modal.on("show.bs.modal", function () {
            $("#authModalContent").load("/login/",function(){
               $("form").on("submit", function(e){
                   e.preventDefault();
                   var data = $("form").serializeArray();
                   $.post("/login_check",data,function(data){
                        $("#authModalContent").html(data);
                   });
               });
            });
        });
```

data is basically the html content of /login/ route. How to nest this function without creating an infinite loop?

Context: Login page loaded, click submit, backend redirects to /login/ with POST and then that html is transferred to the modal.

FOSUserBundle + symfony2 used

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am gonna answer my own question. You need to find something in your dom that will always stay there and tell him to look up for specific other dynamic elements.

```
   this.$modal.on("show.bs.modal", function () {
             $("#authModalContent").load("/login/");

            $("#authModalContent").on("submit", "form", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var data = $("form").serializeArray();
                $("#authModalContent").load("/login_check",data);
            });
        });
```

Basically my `#auModalContent`will always be there and `form` will be dynamically loaded each time